How can you transform the format of letters in a list，Character and parameter mutualization?
Q1:How to convert list1 into list2
list1={A, B, C, D, E, F}

list2{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}


Q2:How to convert list1 into list2
list1={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "B1", "C1", "F4"}

list2={a, b, c, d, e, f, b1, c1, f4}


Look up SymbolName[], ToLowerCase[], ToExpression[].

Following Michael E2's suggestion, there are several methods as follows:
to Q1:
list1 = {A, B, C, D, E, F}
ToString /@ list1 // InputForm

SymbolName /@ list1 // InputForm


to Q2:
list1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "B1", "C1", "F4"}
ToLowerCase /@ list1 // InputForm

f4 = {1, 2, 3}
list1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "B1", "C1", "F4"}
ToLowerCase /@ list1 // ToExpression


technically your original question would suggest that you don't want the quotes in the output of Q2. In which case you would omit InputForm. actually, let me step back.  In Q1, are the inputs Symbols and the desired output a list of strings? In that case do you need the conversion to InputForm at all? and in Q2, are you trying to produce a list of strings or a list of symbols?

@Tapiocaweasel Your question is excellent, and Michael E2 has indeed considered it very thoroughly. These conversions have practical significance. Ultimately, the goal is to convert to a list of variables. This can be achieved using ToExpression.
